# Image blob storing using python 2.7 and retrieving using php

Tags: php, python, mysql, python-2.7

I am doing work on project.
I want to store image as blob in mysql database using python and want to retrieve it using php.I am working on raspberry pi.

***here is my python code:***

```
import MySQLdb 
import sys
from PIL import Image
import base64
import cStringIO
import PIL.Image

db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', password='mungu',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='watchdogdb')

image = Image.open('/var/www/html/abc.jpg')
blob_value = open('/var/www/html/abc.jpg', 'rb').read()
sql = 'INSERT INTO img(images) VALUES(%s)'    
args = (blob_value, )
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,args)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

///
***here it is my php code :***

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, image_time, ext,title FROM {$table} ORDER BY id DESC limit 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty
    echo '<ul><li>No images loaded</li>';
else
{
    echo '<ul>';

    echo "<table border=1>";

    while(list($id, $image_time,$ext,$title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        // outputing list

        echo "<td>";
        echo "  <img height = 200 width='100' src='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'> ";
        echo " <br> <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'>{$title} </a> ";

        echo " <br> <small>{$image_time}</small> ";
        echo "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tabel>";
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Please guide me for this It is important or give another solution to fulfil my requirements.

Thanks in Advance:)